How to create moratorium loan in apache finaract
I want to create moratorium loan in apache fineract with correct interest calculation. How can I do that?
I tried creating loan loan product and then attach loan product to client with 6 month grace on interest and principle. But when checking repayment schedule its not showing correct interest.
